# How to print a jOrgChart chart

Tags: javascript, printing, charts, html2canvas

I have developed a chart using the help of jOrgChart plugin.

Now i have to print that chart.

Unfortunately the chart is too big for the page to handle. So i have to scroll to the left and bottom to see the full chart.

Currently i am using html2canvas to print the chart. But i cannot print the whole chart because it prints only one visible part of the screen.

is there a way to print the whole jOrg Chart .

[image: this is the print i get now]

Comment: Which version of html2canvas are you using?

Comment: html2canvas 0.4.1 <http://html2canvas.hertzen.com>

Comment: @Jen any luck. on this

Comment: Can you show a demo of your code...because i faced the same problem with version 0.5 not with 0.4. I dint have to scroll anywhere as the image was perfectly created without any need of it.

Comment: @Abhishek i am running it locally with db data.. i am unable to put it live.

Comment: what is the size of image you are getting?
You can try setting the height and width of your chart to a specific value. By this you can limit the width of image/chart on your page and html2canvas will get it perfectly.

Comment: yes, from where can i set the height of the chart. ? @Abhishek

Comment: Without the code i will not be able to tell you clearly....

Comment: var currentProject = '@Session["projectId"]';
$.ajax({
  url: "/WBS/GetWBSJOrgChart?id="+currentProject,
  type: "POST",
        success: function (output) {
                  
 $('#chartDiv').html(output);
        $("#org").jOrgChart({ chartElement: '#chartDiv' }, { depth: -1 });                                 });   this is all what i have used..